# How to add border or outline for piechart in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

How to add outline or border for piechart in achartengine.

So far i did

in DefaultRenderer

```
DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(0);
mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(0);
mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(0);
mRenderer.setLegendHeight(0);
```

in piechartview

```
GraphicalView mChartView  = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(AccountSummaryExp.this, mSeries1, mRenderer);
mChartView3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circular_border);
```

what i'm getting is [image: pie chart border covers more than chart] 
pie chart border covers more than chart. I want to wrap the border only to the pie chart. Am i missing something.

Any leads or help are much appreciated.

Thx in adv.